# Facebook newsfeed example

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-feed

I'm trying to access the news stream to pan for certain events

I'm running into a few issues with the facebook developer toolkit.

does anyone have or can point me to an example of getting the news stream?

Comment: Check out http://fbexchange.net/ for Facebook dev questions :)

Comment: is that site part of the SO universe (i know it runs SO software).

Comment: that site is not part of stackexchange. it doesn't seem to come under CC BY-SA 2.5...

Comment: thanks for down voting my comment made 7 years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Facebook Graph Toolkit](http://fbgraph.computerbeacon.net/) is ideal for this job. Check out http://fbgraph.computerbeacon.net/tutorial/section2/ for an example.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [.NET Facebook API Client](http://facebook.codeplex.com) instead. Follow the [Getting Started using trunk](http://facebook.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started%20using%20Source%20Control%20Trunk&referringTitle=Documentation) instructions, and from there using Stream.Get should be fairly straightforward